# Problema con un IF en un SELECT de MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

Estoy creando la base de datos de un sistema de inscripciones para un torneo, lo que estoy intentando es hacer una tabla general con todas las inscripciones, ya que en el torneo hay varios eventos los cuales los podemos llamar A, B, C Y D y un atleta se puede inscribir en 1 o en varios eventos. Dependiendo de la cantidad de eventos en los que se inscribe es el monto que tiene pagar. Por el momento he creado una tabla **INSCRIPCIONES** la cual luce así

```
CREATE TABLE INSCRIPCIONES(
ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
ID_ACA_FK INT NOT NULL,
NOMBRE_ATLETA VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(ID_ACA_FK)
REFERENCES ACADEMIA(ID_ACADEMIA)
);
```

Luego hice un select con un count para contar cuantas veces se ha repetido el nombre de ese atleta para determinar el precio que tiene que pagar, esta es la forma en que lo hago,

```
SELECT NOMBRE_ATLETA, COUNT(NOMBRE_ATLETA) EVENTOS,
IF(EVENTOS = 1, 15000, IF(EVENTOS = 2, 20000, IF(EVENTOS = 3, 25000, IF(EVENTOS = 4, 25000, 0)))) AS MONTO_A_PAGAR
FROM INSCRIPCIONES WHERE ID_ACA_FK = 1
GROUP BY NOMBRE_ATLETA HAVING EVENTOS >= 1;
```

Sin embargo, me da un error que dice **Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'EVENTOS' in 'field list'**

Si corro el select sin el if, si me dice la cantidad de eventos,

```
SELECT NOMBRE_ATLETA, COUNT(NOMBRE_ATLETA) EVENTOS
FROM INSCRIPCIONES WHERE ID_ACA_FK = 1
GROUP BY NOMBRE_ATLETA HAVING EVENTOS >= 1;
```

El resultado es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Comment: mas fasil usar case por lo que veo estas aninando if de forma incorrecta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso, como te dijeron en comentarios, usa el `CASE`.

Trata a tu tabla como subquery y el script queda de la siguiente forma:

```sql
select tablota.*,
       case tablota.EVENTOS
        when 1 then 15000
        when 2 then 20000
        when 3 then 25000
        when 4 then 25000
       else 0 end as monto_a_pagar
from ( 
SELECT NOMBRE_ATLETA, COUNT(NOMBRE_ATLETA) EVENTOS
FROM INSCRIPCIONES WHERE ID_ACA_FK = 1
GROUP BY NOMBRE_ATLETA HAVING EVENTOS >= 1 ) as tablota
```

Comment: Excelente! Me funcionó muy bien, que pasa si quisiera sumar la columna de monto_a_pagar?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta usar case en lugar de if

```
WHEN EVENTOS = 1 THEN 15000
```

Relacionados:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp

Comment: Disulpa, cómo lo podría usar de esa forma?

Comment: Creo que en tu caso particular seria algo asi:


SELECT NOMBRE_ATLETA, COUNT(NOMBRE_ATLETA) EVENTOS,
CASE
    WHEN EVENTOS = 1 THEN 15000
    WHEN EVENTOS = 2 THEN 20000
 WHEN EVENTOS = 3 THEN 25000
 WHEN EVENTOS = 4 THEN 25000
    ELSE 0
END AS MONTO_A_PAGAR
FROM INSCRIPCIONES WHERE ID_ACA_FK = 1
GROUP BY NOMBRE_ATLETA HAVING EVENTOS >= 1;

Comment: Aún me sigue saliendo el mismo error, Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'EVENTOS' in 'field list' creo que es porque no está tomando el nombre que le estoy dando al count para dar el resultado "EVENTOS"

Comment: SELECT NOMBRE_ATLETA, COUNT(NOMBRE_ATLETA) EVENTOS,  
CASE WHEN EVENTOS = 1 THEN 15000 WHEN EVENTOS = 2 THEN 20000 WHEN EVENTOS = 3 THEN 25000 WHEN EVENTOS = 4 THEN 25000 ELSE 0 END AS MONTO_A_PAGAR 
FROM INSCRIPCIONES WHERE ID_ACA_FK = 1 GROUP BY NOMBRE_ATLETA HAVING EVENTOS >= 1; Así es como lo estoy haciendo